# How to instruct RestorePackages to use the NuGet.config file's repositoryPath for the package output path?

Tags: nuget, f#-fake

I am attempting to migrate a CCNET based build script to a F# Fake based one. I am having difficulty understanding how to modify the RestorePackages method to honor the NuGet.config file that instructs NuGet to place the packages in a folder named 'External' several layers deep in our repository.

NuGet.config Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="Code\DotNet\External\" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

NuGET CCNET Example:

```
<exec executable="Tools\NuGet\nuget.exe">
    <buildArgs>restore $[$CCNetWorkingDirectory]\Code\DotNet\Web\All.sln</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

In the above examples I am simply telling NuGet to restore packages for all the projects in the solution. This honors the settings in NuGet.config.

NuGet Fake Example:
    Target "RestorePackages" (fun _ ->
        RestorePackages()
    )

However, calling RestorePackages() does *not* honor NuGet.config (as this method simply uses default parameters) and so my packages are updated in the wrong location.

Ideally I would like to instruct RestorePackages to look specifically at the Visual Studio solution file as I do with CCNET. Is this possible?

If that is not doable, I would like to instruct RestorePackages to honor the settings in the NuGet.config file.

However, if neither are doable, I'll need to be able to override the Output path. Unfortunately, I am having difficult time understanding [the documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-restorepackagehelper.html) and I am not sure how to construct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been reading over the [documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-restorepackagehelper.html) and the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/RestorePackageHelper.fs) for the RestorePackagesHelper module and found that it does not support what I want to acheive, at least not directly due to two limitations.

**Limitation 1: No Solution File Support** - The current RestorePackage implementation uses the [NuGet Install Command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command) which does not support passing in a solution file. In order to pass in a solution file one would need to use the [NuGet Restore Command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Restore_command). Therefore this is not a direct Fake equivalent for what the CCNET snippet listed in the question.

**Limitation 2: No ConfigFile Support** - Further, the RestorePackageParams type does not have a ConfigFile parameter so I am unable to specify the ConfigFile that I want to use in for the NuGet restoration.

These are current limitations of Fake. Not NuGet.

**A Reasonable Solution** - However, I can achieve a similar effect with Fake by scanning for all packages.config files in a given directory and calling RestorePackage for each one; each time specifying the OutputPath as shown below.

***Fake NuGet RestorePackages Example***

```
Target "RestorePackages" (fun _ ->
    !! "./**/packages.config"
        |> Seq.iter (RestorePackage (fun p ->
            { p with
                OutputPath = "./Code/DotNet/External"}))
)
```